# Uninstall Visual F#

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

I use Visual Studio 2013, and it have a pretty feature to notify and install all extension updates.

So, this is very good, but I receive sometimes the request to install the updates for the features I never use.

By example, it proposes me to install the update for the **Visual F# 3.1**

Is there a way to completely remove this F#? I tried to uninstall from the extensions manager, it sends me to the "Add & Remove Programs", but there is any program containing "F#".

How to proceed?

Comment: Same I have `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.1\Framework\v4.0\Fsi.exe` on my computer, but no item in control panel to uninstall it.

Answer (score 5):

There is an awesome package which will do the searching of packages for you called [TotalUninstaller](http://totaluninstaller.codeplex.com/) by Codeplex user [konste](http://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/konste).

Download the package and unpack it to e.g. C:\TotalUninstaller.

It is a commandline program, you need a cmd.exe with administator privileges (click start -> enter "cmd" -> right click on the entry -> select "start as administrator"). Navigate to the directory via

> c: && cd \ && cd TotalUninstaller

In order to list all installed packages you would enter

> TotalUninstaller.exe /ListAll > list.txt

This can be an overwhelming list, so i used a pipe so the content can be viewed with an editor (just open list.txt).

But this is actually not really needed, as there is a file called "TotalUninstaller.exe.config" which features a section  where one can define keywords to filter the installed packages by. It comes with a quite handy default set.

In order to view the selection after the filter was applied, enter

> TotalUninstaller.exe /Filter

Those are the packages that the program currently would remove. If you are happy with the selection, enter the following, **THERE WILL BE NO FURTHER CHECK OR QUESTION**

> TotalUninstaller.exe /Uninstall

and watch the packages disappear. Id close all other applications prior to the last call.

Comment: Looked like it was uninstalling all of these in config file... However, after PC Reboot, NONE of the extensions have been removed :(

Comment: @monstro did you start the console with admin rights?

Answer (score 4):

You can uninstall it with the following command from an PowerShell prompt that has admin rights:

```
gwmi Win32_Product -Filter "Name LIKE '%f#%'" | foreach { $_.Uninstall() }
```

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: This does not uninstall all F# functionality and templates, just two F# packages.

I did a search in the registry for “F#”. I found the location of the installer package for F# v3.1. The MSI installer supports manual uninstallation of such a package. So, using the paths in the registry, I uninstalled them. There are actually two packages: **Visual F# 3.1 SDK** and **Visual F# 3.1 VS**. To uninstall these two packages, an Administrator command prompt needs to be opened.

1. Open a powershell (or command) prompt as an Administrator
2. Run the following to uninstall the **Visual F# 3.1 SDK** package:

   `PS C:\>  msiexec /x "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{06EEE072-B561-38E5-85D9-485ABCBE8342}v12.0.21005\packages\fsharp\FSharpSDK.msi"`

   There is a prompt to perform the uninstallation, and then it’s gone.

   [image: F# v3.1 SDK uninstallation prompt]
3. Run the following to uninstall the **Visual F# 3.1 VS** package:

   `PS C:\>  msiexec /x "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{6321F2D4-366B-3AE4-877A-8E539EC3331A}v12.0.21005\packages\fsharp\FSharpVS.msi"`

Unfortunately, this does *not* make the Visual F# installation go away in the *Extensions and Updates* list, nor does it remove all F# templates. I didn't experiment with manually removing that from Visual Studio (perhaps another day).