# Visual Studio extension conflict when removing a project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

After I save the changes of a solution and then remove an existing project, I'll get the following error message:

```
The operation could be completed. Not implemented.
```

Then I launched `devenv.exe /Log` and able to reproduce the problem and the errors are:

```
Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same ID &apos;Microsoft.Windows.DevelopmentKit.Desktop&apos; is already loaded at 
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\8.0\DESKTOP SDK\
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\8.1\DESKTOP SDK\

Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same ID &apos;Microsoft.WinJS&apos; is already loaded at 
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT SDKS\WINDOWS\V8.1\EXTENSIONSDKS\MICROSOFT.WINJS.SHARED\VSIX\
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT SDKS\WINDOWS\V8.0\EXTENSIONSDKS\MICROSOFT.WINJS.SHARED\VSIX\
```

It looks like it's trying to load two extensions but with different versions. I believe they are the `Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows 8.1` and `Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows Phone 8.1` but even if I launch VS 2012 with Admin, the `Uninstall` button is greyed out for me. I don't see them in the `Add/Remove Programs` either. So how can I get rid of this error?

A side note, I have both VS 2012 and VS 2013 installed and I had to do a repair on VS 2012 after VS 2013 was installed.

Comment: Found a solution to remove the extensions and problem is gone!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134693/how-to-uninstall-the-microsoft-advertising-sdk-visual-studio-extension/24449757#24449757

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Microsoft Windows Development Kit: two errors every time at Visual Studio start with description in the
`%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ActivityLog.xml`

Sometimes (I think every time) Visual Studio Updater or Installer (when you try to install other version of VS) does not remove already installed version of a VS module.

In my case I had the second WDK with older version but installed after the newer one. I manually uninstalled the older version of Microsoft Windows Development Kit and problem with Visual Studio was solved.