# Visual Studio 13 raises unknown error at the startup?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

As I start visual studio 13 it raises unknown error by saying "Microsoft Visual Studio 2014 has stop working" without any further explanation.

Here's what I've tried to solve this problem;

- I reinstall .Net framework
- I repair, uninstall-install Visual Studio
  2013
- I installed another version of VS13

but still the problem persists. Do you have any further suggestion ?

I am using Windows 8.

Comment: VS has a `/SafeMode` startup flag you could use, that'll rule out add-ons etc. - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx

Comment: How should I run it in that way

Comment: The same way you'd apply a startup flag with any program - create a shortcut pointing to VS, and add the flag to the end of the "target" in properties.

Comment: that worked nice and smooth but how can I find out the problem?

Comment: I'm afraid you're on your own there! Have you recently installed any add ons/have any of them had updates that may have broken them? Worst case, backup and reset the environment, adding things back until you find your culprit. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203820

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar situation described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29607057/875020). Once i find a solution, i will post it there.

As a first attempt i would try to generate a logfile via the [/log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx) option and see if there is a problematic extension that you could disable/[deinstall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28050106/875020), e.g. [NuGet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17312698/875020).

You say you reinstalled VS2013, so the problem might be related to settings. If reverting all settings is an option for you, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17203820/875020) thread on how to truly really reset your settings. This involves calling your devenv.exe with special parameters (e.g. in a cmd.exe), removing files and tinkering with the registry.

Comment: I've tried the pointed thread as well but it have not solved either. Currently I run VS without plugins and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to this or a similar problem if you are starting Visual Studio by loading a solution file.

The symptoms are that a solution that previously could be loaded with no problems, suddenly starts having the unknown error box appear for every project in the solution.  Sometimes you can't see the relationship to the continuous reappearance of the error message and the project loading, because you don't have the solution explorer open, so you aren't even aware there is a correlation.

The solution to this is to use task manager to stop visual studio, confirm with visual studio that you wish to shut it down and then look for the .suo file for the solution you are trying to load.  In VS2012 it appears in the same directory as the solution file and has the extension solutionname.v11.suo while in VS2015 it appears in a hidden .vs directory under the location where the solution file is found, in a folder named for the solution.

Delete this file and the problem will go away.

The .suo file contains the user preferences for the solution you are trying to load and it is perfectly safe to delete it as it is regenerated when you load the solution.

If you are getting the unknown error when you haven't tried to load any solutions, this is probably not the right answer.